# A theorem on the union of functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $ f_k: A_k \to B, k = 1, 2, \cdots, n $ be functions. Suppose that for all $ i = 1, 2, \cdots, n $ and $ j = 1, 2, \cdots, n $, $ f_i \cup f_j: A_i \cup A_j \to B $ is a function. Then why is $ \bigcup_{k = 1} ^n f_k: \bigcup_{k = 1} ^n A_k \to B $ a function? (or is it?)

Comment: how are $f_i \cup f_j $ defined? Also, are $A_k$ disjoint sets?

Comment: Where do you send a point residing in multiple $A_i$s?

Comment: @Randall: In case that is a real question and not a hint: That's exactly what the condition is for.

Comment: @JayTuma: As far as I know, in set theory, a function $ f $ is defined as a set of ordered pairs such that if $ (x, y) \in f $ and $ (x, z) \in f $, then $ y = z $.Therefore $ f_i \cup f_j $ means the union of those sets of ordered pairs. Also the sets $ A_k, k = 1, 2, \cdots, n $ are not necessarily disjoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $f_k$ to be a function, for all $x \in A_k$, we have a unique $f_k(x)$ value.

Given, the condition, we want to check if $\bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k \to B$ is still a function. Hence we union all the ordered pair. we need to check that $\forall x \in \bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k$, there is a unique image.

Since we are taking union, we are sure an image exists but we still have to check for uniqueness of image. Suppose there is a conflict, the conflict comes from $(x, f_i(x))$ and $(x,f_j(x))$ and $f_i(x) \neq f_j(x)$.

But we have assume that $f_i \cup f_j$ is a function, i.e. there is no contradiction when we take any two functions and union them, that is $f_i(x)=f_j(x)$. Hence the conflict described above doesn't happen and  hence the image is unique.

Answer (score 1):

We have to prove that
$$ \forall x \in \bigcup_{k=1}^n A_k \quad \exists! y \in B: \quad (x,y) \in \bigcup_{k=1}^n f_k$$

The existance of such $y$ is trivial, so we shall prove the uniqueness

if $(x,y_1),(x,y_2)\in \bigcup_{k=1}^n f_k$, such that $y_1 \neq y_2$, then exists $i, j$ such that
$$ (x,y_1) \in f_i \quad \wedge \quad (x,y_2) \in f_j $$
Which contraddicts the fact that $f_i \cup f_j$ is a function

Comment: "Which contradicts …" — No, it doesn't. Rather, $f_i\cup f_j$ being a function implies that $y_1=y_2$

Comment: i should have said that i was taking $y_1 \neq y_2$